# How to use iterators and Async await to query a google cloud spanner table T1 while querying a second table T2 for each record in T1

Tags: sql, async-await, iterator, es6-promise, google-cloud-spanner

I have two tables in Google cloud spanner database - Authors and Books.

const request = {
  schema: [
    `CREATE TABLE Authors (
      AuthorId    INT64 NOT NULL,
      FirstName   STRING(1024),
      LastName    STRING(1024),
      AuthorInfo  BYTES(MAX)
    ) PRIMARY KEY (AuthorId)`,
    `CREATE TABLE Books (
      AuthorId    INT64 NOT NULL,
      BookId     INT64 NOT NULL,
      BookTitle  STRING(MAX)
    ) PRIMARY KEY (AuthorId, BookId),
    INTERLEAVE IN PARENT Authors ON DELETE CASCADE`,
  ],
};

```
export async function findAuthorBooks(authorId) {
  // [START spanner_find_author_books]
  const database = instance.database(databaseId);
  const query = {
    sql: "SELECT * FROM Books As t WHERE t.AuthorId = @authorId",
    params: { authorId },
    types: { authorId: "string" },
  };

  const results = await database.run(query);
  const rows = results[0];
  const result = [];
  rows.forEach((row) => {
    const json = row.toJSON();
    result.push(json);
  });
  database.close();
  if (Array.isArray(result)) return result;
  throw new Error("err");
  // [END spanner_find_author_books]
}
```

Now I want to query all the Authors and for each author, I query all his books and add it like an object. The function findAuthor1() works perfectly fine.

```
export async function findAuthors1() {
  // [START spanner_find_authors]
  const database = instance.database(databaseId);
  const results = await database.run({ sql: "SELECT * FROM Authors" });
  const rows = results[0];
  const result = [];
  for (const row of rows) {
    const json = row.toJSON();
    const id = json.vendorId;
    json.notification = await findAuthorBooks(id);
    result.push(json);
  }
  database.close();
  if (Array.isArray(result)) return result;
  throw new Error("err");
  // [END spanner_find_authors]
}
```

But the problem here is, iterators/generators require regenerator-runtime, which is too heavyweight for this guide to allow them. Separately, loops should be avoided in favour of array iterations (according to Eslint).
So, I decided to go with Promise.all as shown in function findAuthors2() below:

```
export async function findAuthors2() {
  // [START spanner_find_authors]
  const database = instance.database(databaseId);
  const results = await database.run({ sql: "SELECT * FROM Authors" });
  const rows = results[0];
  const result = [];

  await Promise.all(rows.map(async (row) => {
    const json = row.toJSON();
    const id = json.vendorId;
    json.notification = await findAuthorBooks(id);
    result.push(json);
  }));
  database.close();
  if (Array.isArray(result)) return result;
  throw new Error("err");
  // [END spanner_find_authors]
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. So how can I make it work or is there a different (better) way of doing it without necessarily using Promise.all? 
Or 
Is there a way to write a subquery that will select Books as Array of structs and add to the main query selecting Authors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or Is there a way to write a subquery that will select Books as Array
>   of structs and add to the main query selecting Authors?

Yes- using a subquery which returns an Array of Structs: 
(see [Notes about Subqueries](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/query-syntax#subqueries) in Spanner SQL docs)

eg:

```
SELECT 
  a.AuthorId, 
  a.FirstName, 
  a.LastName, 
  a.AuthorInfo,
  ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT
          b.BookID, b.BookTitle
        FROM
          Books b
        WHERE
          a.AuthorId = b.AuthorId) as Books
FROM
  Authors a;
```

You will have to unpack the array of structs that is returned as the Books column in your code...

There is also the simpler method: just join the 2 tables and get a row per author/book combination, and detect in your code when the AuthorID changes

```
SELECT 
  a.AuthorId, 
  a.FirstName, 
  a.LastName, 
  a.AuthorInfo,
  b.BookID,
  b.BookTitle
FROM
  Authors a, Books b
WHERE
  a.AuthorID = b.BookID
ORDER BY
  a.AuthorID;
```

Comment: I didn't need to unpack the array of structs that is returned as the Books column in the code. I was just perfect as I needed it to be. Thanks a lot.